# Error while installing tsd jade

Tags: node.js, pug, tsd

I'm trying to tell Microsoft Visual Studio Code to show Intellisense options for `.jade` files.

I dont' know if it's possible or not, but like node and express, i used to try `tsd query jade --a install` and got this error:

```
D:\1. Projects\41. WorkorderHelp>tsd query jade --a install

- jade / jade

>> running install..
[ERR!] cwd  : D:\1. Projects\41. WorkorderHelp
[ERR!] os   : Windows_NT 6.3.9600
[ERR!] argv : "node" "C:\\Users\\zakeri.h\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\tsd\\build\\cli.js" "query" "jade" "--a" "install"
[ERR!] node : v0.12.2
[ERR!] tsd  : 0.6.4
[ERR!] Error: read ECONNRESET
[ERR!] CODE : ECONNRESET
[ERR!] read ECONNRESET

This is most likely not a problem with tsd itself
and is related to network connectivity.
In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
'proxy' config is set properly.  See:     https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#tsdrc
[ERR!] .tsdrc could not be retrieved

[ERR!] Please include the following file with any support request:
    D:\1. Projects\41. WorkorderHelp\tsd-debug.log
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try reconnecting your network or doing it over a different network? It says the problem is probably a network problem.

Comment: Yes, I can install other libraries, else than jade. Am I doing it right at all? and will this add intellisense oprtions?

Comment: I have no idea. I was just pointing out the obvious. =) Sorry.